# Django: got error when make Post request: CORS policy: Request header field body is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: django, cors

I installed `django-cors-headers` and have set everything correct in settings.py

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
...

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', # new
...
```

Here is how I make post request:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/isaapi/isaitem/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          body: "" //JSON.stringify(body)
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log(json);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

I checked the response's header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 08:22:27 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.3
Vary: Origin
```

which shows I already got `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Also tried clearing cache but still getting Error as shown below

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/isaapi/isaitem/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field body is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Anyone knows what's wrong here ?

Comment: do you add `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` before `django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware` ?

Comment: @A.Raouf thanks for the comment, yes, I put corsheaders at the top of middleware

Comment: `'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware','django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',`
Add those before it, and try from postman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typo.

In your `fetch` call you put the `body` definition inside the `headers` object. That's why the error message says:

> Request header field ***body*** is not allowed by...

Comment: LOL, I am so dumb... Thanks so much for helping me this!

Comment: Off-topic questions mustn't be answered. They avoid Roomba.

Comment: @double-beep: Yes, for typos I would normally comment and vote to close. In this case, I felt that the answer could help others by showing how to interpret the error message.